# Add multiple actions to a Core - Data relationship at one time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

In my app there should be the ability to add a action to multiple members. I already have the ability to select multiple members and push them to the next `ViewController` where the user can add the action. I already have this function for one member.

There is the code for one member:

```swift
 @IBAction func addTransactionButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let transaction = Transaction(money: Double(moneyTextField.text!) ?? 0.0, date: datePicker.date , reason: reasonTextField.text ?? "")
        do{
            try transaction?.managedObjectContext?.save()

        } catch{
            print("Could not save transaction")
        }

        let reason = reasonTextField?.text
        let moneyText = moneyTextField?.text ?? ""
        let money = Double(moneyText) ?? 0.00
        let date = datePicker?.date

        if let transaction = Transaction(money: money, date: date, reason: reason)   {
           member?.addToRawTransactions(transaction)



            do{
                try transaction.managedObjectContext?.save()

                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            } catch{
                print("Transaction could not be created")
            }
        }

    }
```

I tried it with replacing `member?.addToRawTransactions(transaction)` with `members?.addToRawTransactions(transaction)` but then there is the error :

> Value of type '[Member]' has no member 'addToRawTransactions'

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an array you have to loop over each item

```
for member in members {
    member.addToRawTransactions(transaction)  
}
```

Are you aware you are creating the same transaction twice, maybe you should remove one of the `let transaction = Transaction(...`  calls?

Comment: Perfect . I first struggled because I add your solution directly under the `if let` line but I had to make a loop with the `if let` too. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: And I wasn't aware that I'm doing the let transaction two times. I was really confused about it, but since this is my first app I wasn't sure if I can delete it. Thank you for that too.